# express отправка email шаблона vue

Tags: vue.js, express, nuxt.js

На frontend - vue, backend - express(nodeJs)

Нужно отправлять email.

Есть ли возможность использовать vue вместо html,или шаблонизатора (например pug)?

Comment: Можете скорректировать вопрос пожалуйста, куда отправить эмейл, что именно вы называете шаблоном vue? Если на фронт с бэка, то на vue не выйдет, ибо vue - не шаблонизатор, можно либо получать эмейл запросом на бэк, либо использовать vue + шаблонизатор.

Comment: https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/guide/

Comment: Это не объясняет вопроса, все равно в конце-концов vue билдится в html и js, так и не понял, что ты имеешь ввиду под шаблоном.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

использовал nodemailer и vue-server-renderer

```js
const Vue = require('vue')
const app = new Vue({
    data: {
        name: 'Alina'
    },
    template: `<div>{{name}}</div>`
})

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'user@gmail.com',
        pass: 'pass'
    }
});

const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()
renderer.renderToString(app).then(html => {
     let mailOptions = {
        from: '...',
        to: '...',
        subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
        html: html
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
})
```

vue генерирует html который отправляется на email